# C# exception for LINQ Select() in immediate window, but same code works when compiled

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, immediate-window

When I execute these code lines

```
var lengths = new CPhqLength[]{new CPhqLength(5, EnumUnitLength.Meter)};
lengths.First().ToString(6)
```

in the immediate window while the execution of my program is interrupted, I get

```
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
```

from the first line and

```
"5,000000 m"
```

from the second line.

But when I use the LINQ method `Select()`, an exception is thrown somewhere and it is stored as an object in the returned collection:

```
?lengths.Select (l => l.ToString (6));
{System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator<Schmoll.SwCore.CPhqLength, string>}
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147024809
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "mc_dictUnitInfoDictionary:  The enum value Meter is not defined in the enum Schmoll.SwCore.EnumUnitLength."
    ParamName: null
    Source: "System.Core"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[[Schmoll.SwCore.CPhqLength, schmoll_swcore_basics, Version=0.24.9000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f8a6c8bb21c5d4a1],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_Items()"
    TargetSite: {Boolean MoveNext()}
```

and I have no chance to debug it in any way. Every breakpoint I set is ignored. No exception settings are respected.
This is a simplified example, but it produces the same failure.
`mc_dictUnitInfoDictionary` is a `static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary`, and it definitly is initialized (because it's used) by the program, which is interrupted when executing the failing line in the immediate window. The keys of that dictionary are of `System.Type`, and

```
public static CUnitInfo GetInfo<TUnit> (TUnit i_unit)
{
  var enumType = i_unit.GetType ();
  if (!mc_dictUnitInfoDictionary.ContainsKey (enumType))
    throw CException.Create_EnumUndefined (nameof (mc_dictUnitInfoDictionary) + ": ", i_unit, null);
```

is used to access the keys.
The exception above is an `ArgumentException` which my code throws if an entry is not found in the dictionary.

How can I find out what is going wrong here?
The same line executes fine if written inside a program.

I am using VS 2019 (v.16.5.5) on Win 10 x64. Compilation for x86 or x64 does not make a difference.

Comment: Why have you not updated to the latest version of Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: @IanKemp: Because we need to update offline on our business computers, which actually is almost impossible: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1034990/visual-studio-offline-installation-and-update-suck.html
Beside that, I don't think it would make a difference.

Comment: What does the `ToString` method on your `CPhqLength` class do? Why do you pass `6` in as the argument? It could be that this is what's raising the exception.

Comment: @ChrisF: That `ToString(int)` is like `ToString("F6")` and adds the unit text. And this method actually **is** the problem. It throws if executed via immediate window, but works well if executed in the code. And I don't understand why, because this method had been executed without problems before I ran it in the immediate window, therefore I expect it to work there, too.